Every elliptic surface contains only finitely many negative self-intersection rational curves?
By a properly elliptic surface, I mean an algebraic surface $X$ with Kodaira dimension $\kappa(X)=1$. It has a natural elliptic fibration $\pi\colon X\rightarrow S$.
According to section 5.2 of this article, when $g(S)>0$, $X$ contains only finitely many rational curves. And it states that:

Let $\pi\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ be a very general properly elliptic surface, then $S$ has no rational curves other than the zero section and the components of the singular fibers(hence $X$ contains only finitely many rational curves).

There indeed exists $\pi\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $X$ contains infinitely many rational curves. However, I wonder if there are only finitely many negative self-intersection $\mathbb{P}^1$ on every properly elliptic surface $X$.
Any hints and references would be appreciated.

Welcome new contributor.  Let $\rho:Y\to\mathbb{P}^1$ be an elliptic K3 surface with countably many sections (e.g., a double cover of a rational elliptic surface).  The relative dualizing sheaf of $\rho$ is $\rho^*\mathcal{O}(2).$. Thus, for every morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $>1$ that is unbranched over the discriminant locus of $\rho$, the basechange $\mathbb{P}^1\times_{f,\mathbb{P}^1,\rho} Y$ is such a surface.

I am just posting my comment as one answer.  Let $\varpi:Z\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be the rational elliptic surface obtained by blowing up the projective plane along base locus of a general pencil of plane cubics, i.e., $9$ points.  There are $9$ rational curves in $Z$ that are exceptional for the blowing up morphism.  Use one of those rational curves, $E_0$, as the identity section of the elliptic surface.  For each of the other $8$ rational curves, $E_i$, $i=1,\dots,8$,  there is an automorphism $\tau_i$ of the $\varpi$-smooth locus over $\mathbb{P}^1$ that translates $E_0$ to $E_i$.  The subgroup generated by the automorphisms $\tau_i$ in the group of $\mathbb{P}^1$-automorphisms of the $\varpi$-smooth locus is a free Abelian group of rank $8$.  For every automorphism $\tau$ in this group, the translate of $E_0$ gives one of countably many rational curves with negative self-intersection ( ed. that is a section of $\varpi$).
Now let $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a finite morphism of degree $d$ (ed. whose branch locus is disjoint from the discriminant divisor of $\varpi$).  For $d\geq 3$, the fiber product surface $X:=\mathbb{P}^1\times_{f,\mathbb{P}^1,\varpi} Z$ is a properly elliptic surface.  The base change of the countably many rational curves $\tau(E_0)$ give countably many rational curves on $X$ that each have negative self-intersection.

Hi Jason. Sorry, a question from a non-algebraic geometer, which might be obvious to you (and to others): why are the lifts of the translates of $E_0$ still rational? (For instance, if $\tau(E_0)$ were a multi-section of $\varpi$ I don't see why its lift should still be rational.)

And, more to the point of the question: if $X$ is a proper elliptic surface with infinitely many negative rational curves, does it arise from your construction?

Each of the translates $\tau(E_0)$ is a section of $\varpi$, i.e., the restriction of $\varpi$ to $\tau(E_0)$ is an isomorphism from $\tau(E_0)$ to the codomain $\mathbb{P}^1$ of $\varpi$.  So the same is true for the base change as a curve in $X$.  Moreover, the normal bundle of the base change of $\tau(E_0)$ in $X$ equals the pullback of the normal bundle of $\tau(E_0)$ in $Z$, and this has negative degree.
